# Vim matching based on beginning of lines

Tags: vim

I have a file in which a line can start with `+`, `-` or `*`. In between some of these lines there can be lines (containing those characters as well, but not in column 1!) which start with a letter or a number (general text).

Knowing this, what would be the easiest way to setup a matching & highlighting mechanism, so that a line that starts for example with `+` and all subsequent lines until a line with either `+`, `-` or `*` in column 1, would be highlighted in ... Red?

All ideas welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
syntax region MyRegion start=/^+/ end=/\ze\n[-+*]/
hi MyRegion guifg=red ctermfg=red
```

If you want to integrate it with your current colorscheme rather use:

```
hi link MyRegion Keyword
```

(or Comment, Identifier, Constant, etc.)

**Note**. This means the region ends on the line *before* the next `-`,`+`or `*` at the start of next line. Therefore two regions starting with a `+` are contiguous and you won't notice a difference in highlighting.

If you want each region from the line beginning with `+` to the line (**inclusive**) beginning with `+`, `-`or`*` then use:

```
syntax region MyRegion start=/^+/ end=/^[-+*].*/
```